# How to use the Trapezoidal Rule in C

Tags: c

I want to integrate the sin (a * x) * sin (b * x) function using the [trapezoidal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

I would like to be able to enter the values of a and b to the function without defining those values within the function, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float myfunc(float x, float aa, float bb) {
  return sin(aa * x) * sin(bb * x);
}

float trapzd(float (*func)(float), float a, float b, int n) {
  float x, tnm, sum, del;
  static float s;
  int it, j;
  if (n == 1) {
    return (s = 0.5 * (b - a) * (h(a) + h(b)));

  } else {
    for (it = 1, j = 1; j <n-1; j ++) it << = 1;
    tnm = it;
    del = (b - a) / tnm;
    x = a + 0.5 * del;
    for (sum = 0.0, j = 1; j <= it; j ++, x + = del) sum + = h (x);
    s = 0.5 * (s + (b - a) * sum / tnm);
    return s;
  }

int main() {
  printf("%f\n", 2*trapzd(myfunc(float x, 0, 5),0,1,5)); // Not correct
}
```

I understand that in order to integrate myfunc, it should have a single floating argument "x", how could I add more arguments to the myfunc function (aa and bb)?

thanks

Comment: Please pay attention to code layout. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68233482/edit) your question to format the code properly.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile (Probably because you copied part of it to the question). When adding the missing closing brace, it generate a lot of warning. Please trun **all** compiler warning on and fix all. Then [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68233482/edit) your question with fixed code.

Comment: The first argument of `trapzd` is a pointer to function. When calling `trapzd` you must pass the function (use just the name) while currently you are passing the result of the call to the function. It is `trapzd` which will in turn call the function passed in argument. The `x`value needed by the function will be generated by `trapzd` in the [a,b] interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define:

```
typedef double (*Func)(double x, double aa, double bb);
```

Note: I used `double` and not `float` because most math function such as `sin` and `cos` are using `double`. You can use `float` by casting where needed.

The `trapzd` function becomes:

```
double trapzd(Func func, double aa, double bb, double a, double b, int n);
```

And you call it like this:

```
printf("%f\n", 2 * trapzd(myfunc, 0, 5, 0, 1, 5));
```

Of course `myfunc` also uses double like this:

```
double myfunc(double x, double aa, double bb)
{
    return sin(aa * x) * sin(bb * x);
}
```

Inside `trapzd`, you have to call the function passed as first argument. For example like this:

```
return 0.5 * (b - a) * (func(a, aa, bb) + func(b, aa, bb));
```

Note: I have not looked at the details of your math, but it looks suspect and do not match the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Uniform_grid) given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: Thank, I have another question. If I want to put trapzd in a header file to call it from another program, multiple times, how should I write it?. I am a little confused with the pointers.

Comment: **Copy** the line I show in the header file: *double trapzd(Func func, double aa, double bb, double a, double b, int n);*. You must also **move** the typedef in that header file.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be able to enter the values of a and b to the function without defining those values within the function.

I'll show you couple of ways. One needs a change in the signature of the quadrature function (which should be fixed anyway), to pass the parameters. The other will hide those.

#### Changing the quadrature function

In `trapzd`, the user defined function is passed as `float (*func)(float)`, but later `func` is never called, an undefined `h` is used instead.

We could pass the `a` and `b` parameters to `trapzd`, so that those are also passed to `func` every time it is evaluated.

```c
double trapezoidal( double (*fn)(double x, void const *par)
                  , void const *fn_par //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Just trying to be generic. 
                  , double left, double right
                  , int n )
{
    double const delta = (right - left) / n;
    double sum = (fn(left, fn_par) + fn(right, fn_par)) * 0.5;
    for ( int i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    {
        sum += fn(left + i * delta, fn_par);
    }
   
    return sum * delta;
}
```

While `my_func` become

```c
typedef struct {
    double a, b;
} my_func_par;

double my_func(double x, void const *par) {
    my_func_par const *p = par;
    return sin(p->a * x) * sin(p->b * x);
}
```

Then, in `main`

```c
my_func_par params = { .a = 3, .b = 2 };

double const result = trapezoidal(my_func, &params, 0, 1, 100);
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X82ZddtU56xbqArl).

#### Mantain the signature, but with global data

Ditto. Use this version of `trapezoidal`

```c
double trapezoidal( double (*fn)(double x)
                  , double left, double right
                  , int n )
{
    double const delta = (right - left) / n;
    double sum = (fn(left) + fn(right)) * 0.5;
    for ( int i = 1; i < n; ++i )
    {
        sum += fn(left + i * delta);
    }
   
    return sum * delta;
}
```

But, now implement `my_func` this way (in its own translation unit, to hide the parameters):

```c
static double a_, b_;

void set_my_func_parameters(double a, double b)
{
    a_ = a;
    b_ = b;
}

double my_func(double x)
{
    return sin(a_ * x) * sin(b_ * x);
}
```

Used like so

```
set_my_func_parameters(3, 2);

double const result = trapezoidal(my_func, 0, 1, 100);
```

[Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9CGFrSu2bAthIdHX).